# vertical text alignment for UITableViewCellStyleValue2

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i want align uitextalignment top in my uitableviewcell for style = UITableViewCellStyleValue2..

Can any one tell how ?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your cell by adding UILabel as a subview at any place of your cell.

Comment: if I want to use directly use cell.textLabel and cell.detailTextLabel and want to make their vertical alignment top then what ?